# Can't web scrape a table with RVest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a problem with web scraping this website:
https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/pl/warsaw/EPWA

My goal is to get daily observation table. I tried multiple ways, but it doesn't work.

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)




url <- read_html("https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/pl/warsaw/EPWA")
table <- url %>% html_nodes('table')
min <- url %>% 
html()%>%
html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id="inner-content"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/div[1]/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table") %>% 
html_table()
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

"https://api.weather.com/v1/location/EPWA:9:PL/observations/historical.json?apiKey=e1f10a1e78da46f5b10a1e78da96f525&units=e&startDate=20230124&endDate=20230124" %>% 
  request() %>% 
  req_perform() %>%  
  resp_body_json(simplifyVector = TRUE) %>% 
  pluck("observations") %>% 
  as_tibble() 

# A tibble: 29 × 45
   key   class       expire…¹ obs_id obs_n…² valid…³ day_ind  temp wx_icon icon_…⁴ wx_ph…⁵ press…⁶ press…⁷ dewPt heat_…⁸    rh press…⁹   vis    wc  wdir wdir_…˟ gust   wspd max_t…˟
   <chr> <chr>          <int> <chr>  <chr>     <int> <chr>   <int>   <int>   <int> <chr>   <lgl>   <lgl>   <int>   <int> <int>   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <chr>   <lgl> <int> <lgl>  
 1 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      26    2600 Cloudy  NA      NA         32      36    87    30.3     4    30    30 NNE     NA        7 NA     
 2 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      26    2600 Cloudy  NA      NA         32      36    87    30.3     4    31    40 NE      NA        6 NA     
 3 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     4    32    60 ENE     NA        5 NA     
 4 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     4    31    50 NE      NA        6 NA     
 5 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     3    32    60 ENE     NA        5 NA     
 6 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     4    32    60 ENE     NA        5 NA     
 7 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     3    32    20 NNE     NA        5 NA     
 8 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      26    2600 Cloudy  NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     3    32    50 NE      NA        5 NA     
 9 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     4    32    60 ENE     NA        5 NA     
10 EPWA  observation   1.67e9 EPWA   Warsaw   1.67e9 N          36      27    2700 Mostly… NA      NA         34      36    93    30.3     4    32    50 NE      NA        5 NA     
# … with 19 more rows, 21 more variables: min_temp <lgl>, precip_total <lgl>, precip_hrly <lgl>, snow_hrly <lgl>, uv_desc <chr>, feels_like <int>, uv_index <int>, qualifier <lgl>,
#   qualifier_svrty <lgl>, blunt_phrase <lgl>, terse_phrase <lgl>, clds <chr>, water_temp <lgl>, primary_wave_period <lgl>, primary_wave_height <lgl>, primary_swell_period <lgl>,
#   primary_swell_height <lgl>, primary_swell_direction <lgl>, secondary_swell_period <lgl>, secondary_swell_height <lgl>, secondary_swell_direction <lgl>, and abbreviated
#   variable names ¹​expire_time_gmt, ²​obs_name, ³​valid_time_gmt, ⁴​icon_extd, ⁵​wx_phrase, ⁶​pressure_tend, ⁷​pressure_desc, ⁸​heat_index, ⁹​pressure, ˟​wdir_cardinal, ˟​max_temp
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help. How did you access this api key? I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Inspect element -> Network tab. The API Key is autogenerated